# Stop Google maps navigation programmatically

Tags: android

I currently start Google navigation from my application using something like:

```
Intent navigationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + latLong.getLatitude() + "," + latLong.getLongitude()));
```

Does anyone know how I can stop the navigation from my own application?

I have tried killing it but it seems I just do not have permission, is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can stop the navigation from my own application?

You can't. Please allow the user to exit Navigation if and when they feel like it.

Comment: Sadly I thought that might be the answer. The reason I require it is that in my application it can receive "Stop" messages from control which means that the user should no longer proceed to the destination, but I guess I will only be able to provide a message or perhaps have to use another another piece of software to do the navigation to get round the problem.

Comment: @drnly: I am assuming that your "'Stop' messages" are being picked up and handed by a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`. On the one hand, you could have those pop up a dialog-themed activity or something. On the other hand, navigation is something that you don't want to visually interrupt, as the user might get in an accident. Perhaps consider some sort of audio alert -- a voice message indicating that the destination has been canceled.

Comment: Yes, the messages are handled in a service which always runs in the background since it is primarily a messaging application. Currently I do popup a message in a activity with a transparent background styled as a message box (since started from service) and have a loud audible noise which should be enough. I am aware that distractions can cause accidents, but also equally important is stopping users turning up to the destination when not needed is important because it is a waste of time, money turning up when not required and continuing navigation instructions may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one work around which I found, 
Re-start the navigation with the current location, hence the navigation will automatically be finished.

```
public static void startNavigationIntent(Context activity, String destination)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + destination));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And then bring your app to the foreground.

```
Intent bringToForegroundIntent = new Intent(BackgroundLocationService.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        bringToForegroundIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(bringToForegroundIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm ten years late to answer this question, but just in case someone, like me, was still looking for an answer, I came up with a slightly different solution than the one suggested by Osama Ashraf above.

I tried out restarting the navigation by passing the current location, and it works most of the times, but the solution is not super reliable, as it might be that the current location provided by your app differs a bit from the one shown in Google Maps, and when that happens, it will not detect that the navigation finished automatically.

In order to always stop the navigation, I found out that you can pass a destination that is in a place where it's not possible to calculate a route to, like in the middle of the ocean. For example, using "0.0,0.0" as the coordinates will do the job.

```
val uriString = "google.navigation:q=0.0,0.0&mode=d"
val intent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString)).apply {
  addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
}
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

This will open Google Maps app again, so if you want to go back to your app you will need to launch another Intent to do so, probably after a couple of seconds delay, so it has time to handle the Google Maps Intent first. This is the code I use to do so:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    startActivity(intent)
  }, 2000)
```