# On Changing Location from my App, Update Navigation in GoogleMaps app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3, action

I am working on an application that has to do with location change notifications.  Scenario is stated in steps:

1. User gets a location notification in app.
2. To get best route, Presses a button that starts intent for Google Maps app.
3. Now, since user is outside of my app, it gets a notification for new location, from notification goes into app again meanwhile previous route is set in Maps app.
4. Now, user have a new location, again presses the button for best route and this time when Maps app start, it asks about Exit the current navigation.
5. User has to cancel the already running navigation first and then it starts again with new best route. It makes things longer and complex for user.

I want is it as that whenever Maps app start form my app, it starts with new route automatically instead of asking for previous navigation. As user presses the maps button and Google Map app starts it starts with route to new location.

I am using following script in order to open up Google Maps app so that user can find best route.

```
    String muri="google.navigation:q="+apntLat+","+apntLong;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(muri));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this and skip this step of exiting the previous navigation first and then starting a new one? so that every time the Google Maps intent is called, it starts with finding route to New Location, regardless of the fact it had any previous navigation running. Please update. Any suggestions or feedback is welcomed.

Comment: I think you cannot do that. Let the user manually exit the previous navigation route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038199/stop-google-maps-navigation-programmatically